# meaning of "bear someone home"

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, american-english

In the book "Native Speaker", there is "This means that you can get drunk, for the sake of building ambience and camaraderie (and for your own taut nerves), but still keep in mind that you haven't done right if you don't eventually **bear** him home."

Does the bear mean to take or carry so that it means take/carry him home? Does it have the same meaning as in "right to bear arms"?

Is the "bear" expression in this context rare or common?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, it appears to mean **carry** and its use in this context is most unusual. **Bear** followed by a pronoun is generally used to mean **tolerate** and used negatively as in: **I can't bear her**.

Comment: Can you lift heavier weights if you have bear arms?

Comment: Thank you very much, Ronald for the comment.  Thank you, Smock for the comment. I think I can lift heavier weights if I have bear arms.  May I ask what your  point is, Smock?  Thank you.